# Count All Palindrome Sub-Strings in a String

Tags: python, string, reverse, palindrome

Here I want to find all possible palindromes in a string.

palindrome meaning:- a word, phrase, or sequence that reads the same backwards as forwards,

e.g. madam or nun.

So I took a string. Split it into a list. Then took every element in list at a time. Then took combinations of all the elements until last element of list.

```
a=str(input("enter the string:-"))

b=a.split()

for i in range(len(b)):

    for j in range(i+1,len(b)):

        t=b[i:j]

        r=t.reverse()

        if t == r:

            print(t)
```

I can't get any output even after I wrote the code as logical as I can

For example:-

if `a="Rotator"`

output:-

```
tat
otato
```

and many if possible in it.

I can't find where I have gone wrong, or where loophole is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to convert a string into a list of characters
Here you are trying to convert string into a list of characters, but split method on sting will not give you required character list. For that, you have to us `list(s)`. Instead the best approach is `String Slicing`.

The following code snippet will give you the exact idea.

```py
def isPall(s): 
    return s[::-1]==s

s=str(input("enter the string:-"))

for i in range(1, len(s)+1): 
    start = 0 
    end = i 
    while end<len(s)+1: 
        if isPall(s[start:end]): 
            print(s[start:end]) 
        start+=1 
        end+=1
```

On providing string `madam` this gives output like:

```
m
a
d
a
m
ada
madam
```

Answer (score 0):

Programs have two flaws:

- Split without argument don't really do what you want. It's actually not necessary to split in a list, you can do all operations on a string
- Reverse is an *in place reverse* if you want to get a new value use `reversed`. Here, you are comparing array to None.

Fixed program

```py
a=str(input("enter the string:-"))

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
        t=a[i:j]
        r=''.join(reversed(t))
        if t == r:
            print(t)
```

Outputs:

```
R
o
otato
t
tat
a
t
o
```

Comment: Codes runs very fine, But I can't get how ''.join worked here, as it is used to join elements in list to form a string, and here you haven't converted string to list anywhere.

Comment: @AakibShaikh `reversed` returns a generator, not a string. It's a generic function that can reverse lists, tuples, strings... this is why you have to `join` the return value.

Comment: What's generator ?

Comment: @AakibShaikh Iterators more or less https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on getting the central logic right (two for loops with proper conditions) for getting a palindrome.

Since you are asking us to spot mistakes, I think I can spot two mistakes.
First

```py
b=a.split()
```

I think, may be, you intended to make a list with all characters separated, one character at a time. However split() will look for a separator, which in your case is None. According to the official documentation "If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied". That algorithm is not fitting your requirements.

If all you wanted is separate the characters of a string into a list, you could simply do as below.

```py
b=list(a)
```

Second problem: What is happening in your code is that the b is a list with a single member (which is the string itself). You can check for it by typing the following line, just after you have defined b.

```py
print(b,len(b))
```

This means that the length is 1 for b. This in turn means that the execution enters the first loop but it does not enter the second loop because the condition is range(1,1) which means an empty list!

I have made some minor changes in your code and checked it. Looks like it is giving the result you want.

```py
a=str(input("enter the string:-"))

b=list(a)

for StartSlice in range(len(b)):
    for EndSlice in range(StartSlice,len(b)+1,1):
        ForwardString = "".join(b[StartSlice:EndSlice])
        if ForwardString==ForwardString[::-1] and len(ForwardString)>1:
            print(ForwardString)
```

When I ran the above code for 'xyzrotatorabc' where the palindrome 'rotator' is embedded, I got the following output.

```py
enter the string:-xyzrotatorabc
rotator
otato
tat
```

I am not sure if I was of any help (for the problems you asked for).

Comment: You were exactly upto the point thank you. If b=["sdasda"] and when I give b[0] it correctly returns s, for b[1] d and so on, then why does compiler takes it as a 1 element ?

Answer (score 0):

Two basic assumptions to keep in mind:

(1) 1 char strings/substrings are not considered palindromes, and (2) you want to count ONLY UNIQUE substrings (the original input string is already unique)

```
def count_palindrome_substrings(string):
    # substrings set can only contain UNIQUE values
    substrings = set()
    
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(string) + 1):
            sub = ''.join(string[i:j])
            # is sub a palindrome and is its length greater than 1
            if str(sub) == str(sub)[::-1] and len(sub) > 1:
                substrings.add(sub)

    return len(substrings)
```